# Angular velocity of a ball if force is applied above its center

Tags: angular-momentum, velocity, angular-velocity

I am wondering what the angular velocity would be if you apply a force over time to a ball above its center (but not tangential). For instance, if a ball of was lying on a flat surface and you apply a brief horizontal force at any distance above it center, how would this affect its angular velocity? Would it also affect linear velocity?

Comment: Imparting a short impulse would change the angular momentum of the ball. If it is applied too low, the ball will begin slipping, but if it is applied high enough, it will roll with a uniform velocity. If you want a physical equation, you can start out with the simplest one: $\Delta L = h \Delta p$ and use the rolling without slipping condition.

Comment: @AshmitDutta does h refer to the distance of the force from the ground or the distance of the force from the center of the ball?

Comment: A torque is applied from the instantaneous axis of rotation, which is in this case the center of the ball.